# Optimize a log det function with respect to a matrix, and the saddle point analysis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Suppose I want to to find the local minima of a logdet function $\mathcal{L}$ with respect to a Matrix $\mathbf{A}$, 
$$
\mathcal{L} = \log\vert \mathbf{I} + \mathbf{A}\mathbf{S} \vert - \mathbf{q}^T(\mathbf{A}^{-1} + \mathbf{S})^{-1} \mathbf{q},
$$
where $\mathbf{S}$ is a Symmetric Positive Semi-Definite Matrix, $\mathbf{q}$ is a column vector, $\mathbf{I}$ is an identity matrix. I could find the local minima of $\mathcal{L}$ by solving,
$$
\min_\mathbf{A} \mathcal{L} \qquad \rightarrow \qquad \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \mathbf{A}} = \mathbf{0}.
$$ 
the closed form solution of $\mathbf{A}$ ($\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \mathbf{A}} = \mathbf{0}$) can be derived, 
$$
\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{S}^{-1}(\mathbf{S} - \mathbf{q}\mathbf{q}^T)\mathbf{S}^{-1}
$$

**The questions are**

1. Given $\mathbf{S}$ a positive definite matrix, $\mathbf{qq}^T$ a rank one positive semi-definite matrix, what's the condition that $\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{S}^{-1}(\mathbf{S} - \mathbf{q}\mathbf{q}^T)\mathbf{S}^{-1}$ being a PD(or PSD) matrix ? Is $\mathrm{Trace}[\mathbf{A}] > 0$ sufficient ?
2. How to analyze the stationary point of the partial derivatives $\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \mathbf{A}} = \mathbf{0}$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have used $S^{-1}$ to define $A$, presumably $S$ is positive definite. Now $A$ is p.s.d. if and only if $S-qq^T$ is p.s.d.. Let $Q$ be a real orthogonal matrix with $q/\|q\|$ as its first column. Then
$$
B=Q^T(S-qq^T)Q=\pmatrix{\frac{q^TSq}{\|q\|^2}-\|q\|^2 & v^T\\ v&C}
$$
for some vector $v$ and some positive definite matrix $C$. Therefore $B$ is p.s.d if and only if $\det(B)\ge0$. Using Schur complement, we get $\det(B)=\det(C)\left(\frac{q^TSq}{\|q\|^2}-\|q\|^2-v^TC^{-1}v\right)$. Therefore $A$ is p.s.d. if and only if $\frac{q^TSq}{\|q\|^2}-\|q\|^2-v^TC^{-1}v\ge0$.

As for the second question, I have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I modify your condition $\frac{q^TSq}{\Vert q \Vert^2} - \Vert q \Vert^2 - v^TC^{-1}v \geq 0$ as $q^TSq \geq \Vert q \Vert^2 ( v^TC^{-1}v + \Vert q \Vert^2)$, with $C$ being a PSD, we may let $v^TC^{-1}v=(\lambda - 1)\Vert q \Vert^2$ where $\lambda>1$, and therefore you claim that $q^TSq \geq \lambda\Vert q \Vert^4$, I donnot think this sound right.

Comment: And for the second question, $A$ is PSD iff $\lambda_n(A)>0$ where $\lambda_i(A)$ is the $i$th largest eigenvalue of $A$. I am wondering if there is a more relax condition for the stationary pioint of $\mathcal{L}$. I.e., how could we solve the gradient $\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial A}$ with the constrain that $A$ is PSD, or more specific, with $A$ has a special structure.

Comment: @liubenyuan Hmm, what exactly is not right?

Comment: may be you are right ! I could not find a contradictory. Could we let $\lambda=1$, and then $q^TSq \geq \Vert q\Vert^4$ was the necessary condition that $S - qq^T$ is p.s.d ? Thanks!

Comment: and how do you assert that, $B$ is PSD iff $\mathrm{det}(B)\geq 0$ ?

Comment: @liubenyuan If $B$ is p.s.d., clearly $\det(B)\ge0$. Now the converse is a limiting case of [Sylvester's criterion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion): suppose $\det(B)\ge0$. If $\det(B)\color{red}{>}0$, apply Syl. crit. to the *trailing* (rather than leading) principal minors of $B$ to show that $B$ is *positive* definite. If $\det(B)=0$, then $\det(B+\epsilon)>0$ for sufficiently small $\epsilon>0$. Apply Sylvester's criterion to $B+\epsilon I$, we see that it is positive definite. Take $\epsilon\to0^+$, we see that $B$ is p.s.d..

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you made a sign error in deriving your analytical result.  It should be
$$
\mathbf{A} = -\mathbf{S}^{-1}(\mathbf{S} + \mathbf{q}\mathbf{q}^T)\mathbf{S}^{-1}
$$
which is negative definite.

Comment: Sorry I surely made a sign mistake. I have corrected it.

Comment: @liubenyuan You altered your function by flipping the sign on $qq^T$, but you still have an overall sign error.  I get the feeling that you'd really like $A$ to be positive, but it's not.

Comment: I get a vector of $\mathbf{A}_i, i\in\{1,\cdots,N\}$, however not all of them are relevance. I need to find the minima of $\mathcal{L}$ by inspecting the first and second partial derivatives w.r.t $\mathbf{A}_i$, and using the p.s.d constrains as a **filter**.

Comment: That is, find a simple test that whether $\mathbf{A}_i$ is psd or not.